# Android Change App Icon in code

Tags: android, icons

Is it possible to change an Android App icon in code? Like basically have multiple icon files in the res directory and then on user selection rename one to icon.png and rename the others to other names?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, files in the resource directories can't be renamed through code. If I am mistaken please tell me the way.